# need help using jquery selectors to select a specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Everyone I need some help selecting specific elements in a sidebar to add and remove a Active class
and I don't want to repeat my self with using the next().next() selector in jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        //toggle class Active from sub menu items
        $('.w3-card a').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('active-menu').siblings().removeClass('active-menu');
            $(this).parent().next().next().children().removeClass('active-menu');
            $(this).parent().next().next().next().children().removeClass('active-menu');
            $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().children().removeClass('active-menu');
            $(this).parent().prev().prev().children().removeClass('active-menu');

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-light-grey w3-card" style="width:200px;">
        <!-- Home Link -->
        <a href="index.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="_top">Home</a>
        <!-- Group 1 -->
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-left-align" onclick="myAccFunc1()">
            iLearn Basics
            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="demoAcc" class="w3-hide w3-white w3-card">
            <a href="ilearn_basics/essentials.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Essentials</a>
            <a href="ilearn_basics/global_navigation.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Global
                Navigation Menu</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Group 2 -->
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-left-align" onclick="myAccFunc2()">
            Course Work
            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="demoAcc2" class="w3-hide w3-white w3-card">
            <a href="course_work/quizzes-exam.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Quizzes &amp; Exams</a>
            <a href="course_work/assignments.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Assignments</a>
            <a href="course_work/discussion-board.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Discussion
                Board</a>
            <a href="course_work/content-editor.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Content Editor</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Individual links -->
        <a id="my-grade" href="my_grades/my-grade.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">My Grades</a>
        <!-- Group 2 -->
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-left-align" onclick="myAccFunc3()">
            Communication
            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="demoAcc3" class="w3-hide w3-white w3-card">
            <a href="communication/bb-email.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Email in iLearn</a>
            <a href="communication/notifications.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Notifications</a>
            <a href="communication/social.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Social Learning Tools</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you want to remove the active-menu class from links of same group or all the links?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can shorten it like:

```
$('.w3-card a').click(function(){     
    $('.active-menu').removeClass('active-menu');
    $(this).addClass('active-menu').siblings().removeClass('active-menu');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be removing the `active-menu` class from all the links when a link is clicked. For that purpose you can use the following code:

```
$('.w3-card a').click(function(){
  $('.w3-card a').removeClass('active-menu');
  $(this).addClass('active-menu');
});
```

Working sample:

```js
$('.w3-card a').click(function(){ 
  $('.w3-card a').removeClass('active-menu');    
  $(this).addClass('active-menu');
});
```

```css
.active-menu {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-light-grey w3-card" style="width:200px;">
        <!-- Home Link -->
        <a href="index.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="_top">Home</a>
        <!-- Group 1 -->
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-left-align" onclick="myAccFunc1()">
            iLearn Basics
            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="demoAcc" class="w3-hide w3-white w3-card">
            <a href="ilearn_basics/essentials.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Essentials</a>
            <a href="ilearn_basics/global_navigation.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Global
                Navigation Menu</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Group 2 -->
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-left-align" onclick="myAccFunc2()">
            Course Work
            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="demoAcc2" class="w3-hide w3-white w3-card">
            <a href="course_work/quizzes-exam.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Quizzes &amp; Exams</a>
            <a href="course_work/assignments.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Assignments</a>
            <a href="course_work/discussion-board.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Discussion
                Board</a>
            <a href="course_work/content-editor.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Content Editor</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Individual links -->
        <a id="my-grade" href="my_grades/my-grade.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">My Grades</a>
        <!-- Group 2 -->
        <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-left-align" onclick="myAccFunc3()">
            Communication
            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="demoAcc3" class="w3-hide w3-white w3-card">
            <a href="communication/bb-email.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Email in iLearn</a>
            <a href="communication/notifications.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Notifications</a>
            <a href="communication/social.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" target="contentFrame">Social Learning Tools</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you want to remove the `active-menu` class from links of same group only, just replace the JS with the following js:

```
$('.w3-card a').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active-menu').siblings().removeClass('active-menu');
});
```